# Replicate a database to one secondary replica, but not the other secondary replica using Availability Group

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups

I have a 3 nodes cluster in an availability group.  There are two databases on the primary node.  One database I want to replicate to the 2 secondary nodes.  Another database I just want to replicate it to 1 secondary replica, not the other.  In the wizard, you have to select both nodes.  Is there a way to set it up using T-SQL so that one database only replicate to one secondary node, but not the 3rd node?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using them differently, why do they need to be in the same availability group? Just create two different groups...

Answer (score 0):

You can setup 2 different availability groups and add databases accordingly, so that way you can manage it separately.

Comment: Can I share the AG listener?  It's having error 41009 when tried to add it.